# check user in group SPFX get Httpclient request 403

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I get a 403 error when i try to check if a user is part of group.

```
 let props = this.properties;
  let GroupsArray: string[] = [];

  if (props.Groups != null && props.Groups.length > 0) {
    GroupsArray = props.Groups.split(',');
  }
sp.web.siteGroups.getByName(GroupsArray[0]).users.get().then((users) => {
    if (users.filter(i => i.Email == currentUser).length > 0) {
      IsvalidGroup = true;
      this.getBenefitsList(GroupsArray[0]);
    } else {
      IsvalidGroup = false;
    }
  }).then(()=>{
    if (!IsvalidGroup) {
      sp.web.siteGroups.getByName(GroupsArray[1]).users.get().then((users)=>{
        if (users.filter(i => i.Email == currentUser).length > 0) {
          IsvalidGroup = true;
          this.getBenefitsList(GroupsArray[1]);
        }   
      })
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    this.SetError(err);
     console.log(err); }
  )
  return IsMember;
```

Below is the error

```
Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [403] ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check if, in the settings of the group, the `Who can view the membership of the group?` is set to `Everyone`. It is probably set to `Group Members` so you should change it to `Everyone`.

You can check that setting by going to https://SITEURL/_layouts/15/user.aspx , then clicking on group name and choosing the menu item `Settings -> Group settings`.